# Spark job reading from Kafka, single partition resets to '0'

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Structured Streaming job that reads from a Kafka topic with 50 partitions. One of the micro batches is retried. In the first try partition 30 starts and ends with the correct offset value, which of course does not change in this instance.

In the retry attempt, partition 30 (and only 30) starts where the first try left off, but the batch finishes with it having an offset of '0'. Subsequent batches show partition 30 replaying all of its records, until it's caught up.

Any idea what might be causing this? I am not sure why this particular batch was retried either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not really clear to me what is happening here. Can you explain more what you mean with "but the batch finishes with it having an offset of '0'."

Comment: Spark logs the query progress of each micro-batch. This log gives the startOffset and endOffset for each partition in the topic. So the micro-batch starts at offset 1000, for example, for each partition. At the end of the micro-batch the offset indicates progress made, say 1100.

Comment: In my case, I have 50 partitions. The batch is attempted a first time, and no progress is made, so startOffset and endOffset are the same for each partition. This batch is then retried. Progress is made, each partition consumes some records and this is reflected in the endOffset.

With one exception. In my case, partition 30 had a startOffset of 90000, but an endOffset of 0. Something caused it to reset when it really shouldn't. The result was that in the next micro-batch partition 30 had a startOffset of 0, and started to replay all its records.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I have not seen such a behavor before. When the messages of partition 30 are being re-processed, is it always stuck at the startOffset of 90000? I mean, is the problem reproducable?

Comment: How many cores is your stream using and how long is the processing time of the data?

Comment: The error is not reproducible. An explicit replay processed without error, including the 90000 offset.

The stream uses 50 cores, to match the partitions, and trigger interval is 2s. Data is usually processed in < 1s.